# iOS app distribution failed with error ITMS-90635 nested bundle contains arm64(machine code) whereas main bundle contains arm64(bitcode)

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, ios-frameworks, bitcode

I have made my own fat framework that I distribute over Cocoapods.

But when I try to upload an app with bitcode enabled using my framework, I am rejected with error ITMS-90635, see:

[image: distribution failed app store]

I want my framework to be compatible with bitcode, so I set `ENABLE_BITCODE=YES`, `BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode` (also tried with `OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode"` in addition) when building the framework.

Here is how I build my framework:

```
[...]

echo "Clean ${TARGET_NAME} for simulator"
xcodebuild -workspace ${WORKSPACE_NAME}.xcworkspace -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=latest' -scheme ${SCHEME} CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ENABLE_BITCODE=YES BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode clean

echo "Clean ${TARGET_NAME} for generic device"
xcodebuild -workspace ${WORKSPACE_NAME}.xcworkspace -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -destination generic/platform=iOS -scheme ${SCHEME} CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ENABLE_BITCODE=YES BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode clean

echo "Build ${WORKSPACE_NAME} for simulator"
xcrun xcodebuild -workspace ${WORKSPACE_NAME}.xcworkspace -scheme ${SCHEME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=latest' -sdk iphonesimulator CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ENABLE_BITCODE=YES BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode

echo "Build ${WORKSPACE_NAME} for generic device"
xcrun xcodebuild -workspace ${WORKSPACE_NAME}.xcworkspace -scheme ${SCHEME} -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -destination generic/platform=iOS -sdk iphoneos CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO ENABLE_BITCODE=YES BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode

[...]

lipo -create "${DEVICE_BIN}/${TARGET_NAME}" "${SIMULATOR_BIN}/${TARGET_NAME}" -output  "${UNIVERSAL_PATH}/${TARGET_NAME}.framework/${TARGET_NAME}"
```

What I really do not understand is that my framework seems to have bitcode enabled, see:

[image: Bitcode seems to be enabled]

[image: while validating]

Am I doing something wrong when building my framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally found what was wrong :)

Once `lipo` done, I used to copy/paste

`Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/MyFramework.framework/Modules/MyFramework.swiftmodule/`

into

`Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MyFramework.framework/Modules/MyFramework.swiftmodule/`

and then I was distributing this final framework:

`Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MyFramework.framework`.

**Do the opposite**! Once `lipo` done, copy/paste `MyFramework.swiftmodule/`'s `Release-iphonesimulator/` into the `Release-iphoneos/` one and distribute the .framework in `Release-iphoneos/`.

Comment: But then the .framework which is distributed at the end does not have simulator arch inside, right?

Comment: It does include simulator arch. Simulator is included swiftmodule in Release-iphonesimulator. I copied/pasted these swiftmodule into the one in Release-iphoneos.

Comment: And are you able to put this Framework inside an App and upload it to the store without having an error which is complaining about missing bitcode?!

Comment: And you are not using your ${UNIVERSAL_PATH}, which is filled during lipo, at the end?

Comment: Before lipo I first define `DEVICE_BIN="${BUILD_PRODUCTS}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${TARGET_NAME}.framework"`, then `cp -r "${DEVICE_BIN}" "${UNIVERSAL_PATH}"` and finally do lipo

Comment: Would you please post your whole script? That would really help me a lot...

Comment: I can't I am so sorry. The script is full of sensitive data from my company. I mostly inspired from this post https://instabug.com/blog/ios-binary-framework/. Sorry again

Comment: No worries... I already got it working :) Thanks for your help

Comment: do we need to add  Add ‘iPhoneSimulator’ string in ‘CFBundleSupportedPlatforms’ array?